# How can I differentiate a Poisson distribution to find the maximum that way?

Tags: calculus, poisson-distribution

I want to find the maximum to a Poisson distribution using calculus. How can I do this? I want to do this algebraically.

Comment: When you say "maximum", do you mean the mode?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The ratio of two consecutive Poisson probabilities is $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{e^{-\mu}\mu^{n}/n!}=\frac{\mu}{n+1}$. For what $n$ is this ratio greater/less than one?

Answer (score -2):

The Poisson distribution is only defined for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and therefore can't be differentiated.

Comment: but one can graph it as a continuous function, i.e. $y=\frac{m^x e^{-m}}{x!}$. how could I find the maxima of this graph for positive $m$?

Answer (score -2):

One way to show the maximum is using the following method:
$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{−µ}\frac{µ^x}{x!}$ = $e^{−µ}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{µ^x}{x!}$ = $e^µe^{-µ}$ = 1

Comment: As far as I can tell, all you've shown is that the distribution is properly normalized. I see no statement as to why this is helpful for finding the maximum.